# Retrieving selected records from MS access database using SQL query in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have tried the following code to get records of employees.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM employeerecord WHERE [First Name] LIKE '%" & TBFirstName.Text & "%'" &" OR [Last Name] LIKE '%" & TBLastName.Text & "%'" & " OR [Emp ID] LIKE '%" & TBEmpID.Text & "%'"
```

The problem is that by this all records are appearing in the database irrespective of whether any field in the text box is matching with it or not. How do I make it retrieve only those records which are like the data in the text fields? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you want exact match then use WHERE tablename='' without the %

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all three of your text boxes contain Null or an empty string, the `WHERE` clause built by your code will be this ...

```
WHERE [First Name] LIKE '%%' OR [Last Name] LIKE '%%' OR [Emp ID] LIKE '%%'
```

That would return nearly all rows from `employeerecord` ... the only records excluded would be those which contained Null in all three of those fields: `[First Name]`; `[Last Name]`; and `[Emp ID]`.

If only one of those text boxes contained Null or an empty string, the `WHERE` condition based on that text box would still be `LIKE '%%'` and, since the `WHERE` uses `OR`, you would once again get nearly all the rows.

Comment: thanks Hansup... could you please tell me what is the right query so as to get records which closely match the text in the textboxes? If the textboxes are empty then no record should be returned.

Comment: Your code builds the query at run time.  So build it to incorporate the conditions you need based on the text box values.  If you want no records returned when all 3 text boxes are empty, use q `WHERE` clause which evaluates as False for all rows: `WHERE 1 = 2`

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact query i should write? i did not understand how to put your comment in practice.

Comment: In your VB.Net code, check the values of the text boxes.  Build the query differently based on those text box values.  Since you said you want no rows returned when all 3 text boxes are blank: `SELECT * FROM employeerecord WHERE 1 = 2`  But when not all 3 text boxes are blank, build a different query.